# How to scrape data that required login

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to Scraping Data from website Site that require Logins with Python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get("http://ema.todrock.com/list-details/5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("div",class_="table-responsive")
for r in table:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Your script needs to go through the login process of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interact with the site try using [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

**Example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url = 'http://ema.todrock.com/list-details/5'

# keeping it simple: download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put file in same folder as the script.  Firefox driver is available if you search for it
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id('login').click()
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("div",class_="table-responsive")
for r in table:
    print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" id="datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sr</th>
<th>Email id</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> </tr><tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>dave.babbitt@xwave.com</td>
<td>
<span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>
</td>
<td>2019-12-02 10:30 AM</td>
<td>
<a class="m-r-5" href="email-details/32573" target="_blank" title="View List"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye text-success"></i></a>
<a class="m-r-5 edit_details" data-target="#importModal" data-toggle="modal" data-value="32573" href="" title="Edit List"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o text-primary"></i></a>
<a class="m-r-5" href="delete-detail/5/32573" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" title="Delete List"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>dave.barlow@dynamoplaygrounds.com</td>
<td>
<span class="badge badge-danger">Unsubscribe</span>
.......
.........
............etc.
```

If you are looking for email addresses:

```
    for e in soup.find_all('td'):
        if not e.is_empty_element:
            for i in e:
                if '@' in i:
                    print(i)

dave.babbitt@xwave.com
dave.barlow@dynamoplaygrounds.com
dave.beauchamp@nrc.ca
dave.belanger@ubisoft.com
dave.biduk@ottawa.ca
dave.bilowus@royallepage.ca
dave.black@ps-sp.gc.ca
dave.blanchard@newcapradio.com
dave.bland@jpbindustry.com
dave.bon@tc.gc.ca
```